# How to avoid UnicodeDecodeError reading this csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a csv file with data as below:

```
Text                                                        Value
RT @AmericanHot We're DONE! . htt…                           A
RT @votevets: Hertha Berlin German #Bundesliga world.…  
RT @votevets: Hertha Berlin players  # world.…               B
RT @HerthaBSC_EN: Hertha BSC stands forever…    
RT @johanbakerr: There's no anthem played                    D
```

when I read the csv file as

```
df = pd.read_csv('Book1.csv')
```

It gives me below error. I am using python 3.6. Please help.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x85 in position 33: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Your file isn't encoded with UTF-8. You need to find out what the actual encoding is. Or try guessing (eg cp1252) & see what happens. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
 df=pd.read_csv('Book1.csv',dtype='unicode')
```

or

```
  df=pd.read_csv('Book1.csv',dtype='unicode',encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```